# Assumption in Axiom3 of Probability

Tags: probability

As an engineer beginning my formal journey into mathematics focusing on probability, I am currently studying "Probability and Statistics" by Morris H. DeGroot and Mark J. Schervish. In the book, while discussing Axiom 3, the authors make an interesting note. They assume that the additive property of probability holds not only for every finite collection of disjoint events but also for every infinite sequence of disjoint events. By assuming this, they ensure that the additive property remains true even for infinite sequences. However, I have a question: Isn't a convergent series simply a way to extend a finite series by adding an infinite number of zeroes at the end? As a newcomer to this concept, it feels like a kind of trickery. Can you shed some light on this for me, please?

Comment: Can you share the text of the axiom? Some books may number it differently. Include it in the body of the post, please.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite series don't necessarily have to have finitely many nonzero terms, consider the function where two people ($A$ and $B$) are playing a game flipping coins (passing it onto the other if they obtain tails), $A$ begins and the winner is the first to obtain three consecutive heads, and $f(n)$ is the chance that $A$ wins on the $n$th toss, then $f(n)>0$ for all $n>2$.

Expressions in the form$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(p(n)*x^n\right)
$$(where $p$ is a function of $n$) are called generating functions, and are 'rational' (expressible in terms of a fraction of polynomial functions of $x$) if and only if $p(n)$ is linear-recurrent (expressible in terms of a linear recurrence relation, where the $n$th term is a linear combination (sum of fixed weights) of preceding terms). Often, problems in probability will be expressible in terms of linear recurrence relations, and representing them as generating functions is a faster means of solving your problem (ie. the $n$th Fibonacci number (from $F(0)=0, F(1)=1, F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$) is $F(n)=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, but $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(F(n)*x^n\right)=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$). Importantly for probability, these generally only converge (for infinite sequences) for $\left|x\right|<1$, uniquely correspond with the functions that they sum, and can have the original function computed back from them by polynomial division (without the condition that it terminates).